# Key clamping in curve25519 not evident in generated key's binary representation

Tags: elliptic-curves, ed25519, libsodium, x25519

I understand with `curve25519` that the private key for `secret.box` is clamped...

I understand that this clamping process to clear the **lower 3 bits** in order to ensure the key is a **multiple** of 8, ensuring it's part of the right cyclic subgroup.

However, as I generate example keyPairs using sodium such as:

```
a67e2d949d00606d2b6d0d9114d3ee273f118a078151c7aad2b55694ea18bb39 // 1010011001111110001011011001010010011101000000000110000001101101001010110110110100001101100100010001010011010011111011100010011100111111000100011000101000000111100000010101000111000111101010101101001010110101010101101001010011101010000110001011101100111001
```

or

```
b2c80def0dc392671e5143e9804c1083a39c751eec7348383eb586d708b374cc // 1011001011001000000011011110111100001101110000111001001001100111000111100101000101000011111010011000000001001100000100001000001110100011100111000111010100011110111011000111001101001000001110000011111010110101100001101101011100001000101100110111010011001100
```

I noticed that despite being able to positively confirm they are part of the multiple of 8 subgroup, their binary representation does **not** have the lower three bits cleared...

So as you can see above, the binary representation of these random private keys doesn't have `000` for the lowest three bits. Yet when I check in SageMath, I can confirm both of these keys are multiples of 8.

**Update**:
I generated the keys using the libSodium->SecretBox->KeyPair()...

Which internally calls the clamping/scalar multiplication.

I also verified that despite not ending in three zeros `(000)` - the private keys are always of order `7237005577332262213973186563042994240857116359379907606001950938285454250989` and as such are of the correct subgroup.

Any idea why?

Comment: Not clear how did you generate the pairs?

Comment: @kelalaka updated my question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clamping happens as part of the key agreement / signing procedure. The private key itself isn't clamped when stored.

(How did you test the numbers you have provided? None of them seem to be multiple of 8. Also recall that curve25519 keys are in little endian.)

Comment: the keys seem to be always multiples of 8 though, and part of the right group, see updated question... I tested the numbers, by converting the hex to decimal, using Sage to multiply the decimal by the base point and testing the order of the point returned...so the generated keys seem to be clamped.

Comment: Writing the curve order as $8n$ with $n$ prime; the base point has order $n$, so if you multiply it by some $k \neq 0 \bmod p$ the resulting point will also have order $n$. This does not imply that $k$ is a multiple of 8. The clamping protects  ECDH when multiplying with some arbitrary point provided by the other party which may have order different than $n$.

Comment: Ah I got it, so because my base point is of order n, then the resulting point is also order n, irregardless or the scalar. So why do we bother clamping the private key? If we can use any scalar and still be in the right subgroup?

Comment: oh, one more thing, is it possible to exfiltrate the private key in clamped mode @Conrado?

Comment: @Woodstock because on key agreement / public key encryption, the user's private key is multiplied by the other user's public key point. If the other user is malicious, they could send a point with order different than $n$ (e.g. order 8). Clamping the private key prevents that from being a problem. You can simply clamp the scalar yourself, it's up to the library you use if they provide some function for that.

Comment: ah that makes perfect sense thank you!! I can see now why we need to clamp the key.

Comment: last thing, it seems that on key pair generation (of public and private key) the key is clamped during crypto_scalarmult_curve25519_ref10_base, inside https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium/blob/927dfe8e2eaa86160d3ba12a7e3258fbc322909c/src/libsodium/crypto_scalarmult/curve25519/ref10/x25519_ref10.c ... are you sure that the clamping only occurs at key agreement/signing it seems it happens on pair generation in order to calc the pub key. surprised its not clamped when stored, as it seems to be in the code

Comment: Assuming that the scalar has been clamped would be dangerous. The dedicated key generation function could return a clamped scalar, but that scalar can also be a randomly generated bit string, the output of a KDF, or whatever an application decides to use instead of the dedicated function. Clamping just before the scalar is used is cheap and way safer.

Comment: @FrankDenis thanks for the reply sir. So even though the clamped scalar is used to generate the public key point, libsodium stores the public key + Unclamped scalar in the Keypair object?

Comment: @Woodstock yes, it's also done when computing the public key from the private, and anywhere the private key is used in a point multiplication. But the (unclamped) private key stored doesn't change.

Comment: @Woodstock Correct. If you really don't want clampling to happen, this is still an option (`crypto_scalarmult_ed25519_noclamp()` and `crypto_scalarmult_ed25519_base_noclamp()`), but these functions will check that the public key is on the main subgroup, which is slower than clamping. Using the Ristretto encoding may be a better option.